# How to disable Swapfile in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, memory

I've tried these commands in OS X El Capitan, but it doesn't work:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.dynamic_pager.plist

$ sudo rm /private/var/vm/swapfile*

$ sysctl vm.swapusage
vm.swapusage: total = 2048.00M  used = 596.00M  free = 1452.00M  (encrypted)
```

I have 16GB of RAM and 256GB SSD, I just don't want the SSD to tear down faster just because I enable the swapfile.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence - and if you have enough memory OSX won't swap - if tour swapfile is really 596 M then you need more memory to stop swapping

Comment: @Mark What's the problem with swapping?

Comment: @Mark Actually, at this moment I have 7 of 16 GiB memory inactive, but still 1 GiB swap. This is perfectly normal and no problem at all.

Comment: @MaxRied the OP wants to stop swapping

Comment: @Mark Unlimited amount of memory will not prevent it from swapping

Comment: in linux i can easily do this using `swapoff` command '__')

Comment: Note that OSX is not Linux and a lot of very smart OS engineers at Apple have decided that they know more about the OS and it's effects on hardware than you do. Linux is the other way 'round. Both are valid approaches. Many moons ago you could turn off the OSX swap file, it seems that is no longer possible or a dangerously complicated hack for minimal benefits.

Answer (score 5):

El Capitan has its System Integrity Protection system, which you must disable before you can touch some OS inner workings, such as swap.

You'll need to reboot your Mac in Recovery Mode (holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot time). Open Terminal as root, then disable System Integrity with:

```
csrutil disable
```

Now you can disable swap.

After all done, you should enable System Integrity again using:

```
csrutil enable
```